# pointer to void

Tags: c++, pointers, void

This is kind of basic but I can't seem to get a hold on this one. Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707415/sort-of-arguments)

Are `void *p` and `const void *p` sufficiently different? Why would a function use `const void *` instead of `void *`?

Comment: Sufficiently different for what?

Comment: what i mean is that does it make sense to have something as 'const void *'?

Comment: Yes, it's a pointer to an immutable object of unknown type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason to use `void*` at all (whether `const` or not) is the kind of genericity it provides. It's like a base class: All pointers *are* `void*` and can implicitly cast into it, but casts from `void*` to typed pointers have to be done explicitly and manually.

Usually, C++ has better ways to offer to do this (namely OO and templates), so it doesn't make much sense to use `void*` at all, except when you're interfacing C. However, if you use it, then `const` offers just what it offers elsewhere: you need an (additional) `const_cast` to be able to change the object referred to, so you are less likely to change it accidentally.

Of course, this relies on you not employing C-style casts, but explicit C++ casts. The cast from `void*` to any `T*` requires a `static_cast`, and this doesn't allow removing of `const`. So you can cast `const void*` to `const char*` using `static_cast`, but not to `char*`. This would need an additional `const_cast`.

Comment: Nice answer, but I think this is not what's asked. It is the difference between the const and non const version.

Comment: I believe cast from `void *` to `T *` requires `static_cast`. `reinterpret_cast` is always implementation defined and should be avoided.

Comment: I think OP knows the meaning of `const`, he is just saying that he does not understand what to make of a `const void` specifically. So I think this is a good answer. And a good use of `reinterpret_cast`, by the way.

Comment: @Diego: I thought I had written that a `const void*` is useful for the same reason any other const is useful: to prevent accidental changes to an object. To be honest, I'm somewhat at a loss as to how to state this more explicitly. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The last paragraph is wrong, and you should correct it, conversions from and to `void*` are performed with `static_cast` §5.2.9[expr.static.cast]/10

Comment: @David: Yes, you're right! It's conversions between different typed pointers, but not conversions between `void*` and typed pointers. I confused this. I corrected that.

Comment: @sbi: it is just a subtle thing. Yes, you mention that being const is of course to avoid modifying the object passed to the function, but as the question itself was asking just that, that exact phrase was kind of hidden, and the response was a little bit too much elaborated (at least from my point of view). Also, given that void* is usually used to interface C or system calls, usually void* vs. const void* comes just as a hint to tell the caller whether the function is modifying the passed object pointed or not.

Answer (score 2):

In c++ a const in front of a pointer says the data at the pointer's address should not be changed. i.e. it stops someone doing this:

```
int v1 = 3;
int v2 = 4;
const int *pv = &v1;
pv = &v2 // ok;
*pv = 5; // error
```

You can also make the pointer value itself a const:

```
int v1 = 3;
int v2 = 4;
int * const pv = &v1;
*pv = 5; // ok
pv = &v2; // error
```

You can also combine the two:

```
int v1 = 3;
int v2 = 4;
const int * const pv = &v1;
*pv = 5; // error
pv = &v2; // error
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple difference. As other stated, there is little need to use `void*` in C++ due to its better type system, templates, etc. However, when interfacing to C or to system calls, you sometimes need a way to specify a value without a known type.

As you ask, the difference between `void*` and `const void*` is a hint to show you if the contents of the pointed memory will be modified within the function you're calling, the `const` meaning it will have a read-only access.